# Get open terminal output from the script in bash

Tags: bash, scripts, scanner

I wrote a little script in bash that just puts the network card in monitor mode and then launches airodump-ng in a separate terminal to scan.
Here the problem arises, I start airodump in a new terminal like this: konsole -e "**airodump-ng $ interface**" only that I would like to close the terminal where airodump works I get the output in the script so that I can continue the execution but at CTRL + C also closes the first terminal that runs the script.
How can I solve?

Comment: If you want us to audit or help improve a script, you should provide the script.  Use edit to add details.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because the monitoring utility can write its output to a file such as

```
airodump-ng -c 6 -w /root/chan6 wlan0mon
```

You could press Ctrl-C at anytime and be able to continue your analysis based on the data captured in the /root/chan6 output file.

Comment: When i close airodump-ng my script in the main terminal is closed, why?

Comment: After looking at some tutorials such as https://singhgurjot.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/how-to-install-airodump-ng-and-aireplay-ng-in-ubuntu/  It seems that opening a terminal manually would make sense.  Alternatively, you could share something of the script for the AskUbuntu community to analyze.